# Probability Scenarios in a Communication Network with Link Failures

Tags: probability, network

In the communication network given below, link failures are independent, and each link has a probability of failure p. (consider the physical situation). A can communicate with B as long as
they are connected by at least one path which contains only in-service links.

1. Given that exactly five links have failed, determine the probability that A can still communicate with B.
2. Given that exactly five links have failed, determine the probability that either g or h (but not both) is
   still operating properly.
3. Given that a, d, and h have failed (and no other information), determine the probability that A can
   communicate with B.

Comment: No "network given below" = network failure ?